# Linking an asset's CreatedBy field to another user in Content Hub

Tags: content-hub

Is it possible to re-link an Asset's CreatedBy field to another user?

I am aware that this is a system field and possibly uneditable but still would like to know if this is possible at all, either via UI or programmatically.

I played around the REST API and from the looks of it, there's no straightforward way of doing it provided by the documentation.

Comment: Create a new field in the schema, you can play with that, not with the system defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `CreatedBy` is system defined and read-only. You may not be able to edit the system-defined fields. You can create your own field by updating the schema and putting the user information.